# access ant property value for pattern variable in file.eachFileMatch() in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I am unable to run the code for moving file, when i use the ant macrodef attribute in groovy task inside the macrodef.

```
<macrodef name="dirmove">
            <attribute name="todir" />
            <attribute name="fromdir" />
            <attribute name="includes" default="*" />
            <sequential>
                <var name="todir" value="@{todir}" />
                <var name="fromdir" value="@{fromdir}" />
                <var name="includes" value="@{includes}" />
                <groovy>
                File dir1 = new File(properties.'fromdir');
                File dir2 = new File(properties.'todir');  
                def pattern = properties.get('includes')
                println pattern;
                dir1.eachFileMatch  ~/pattern/, { 
                    f-> 
                    boolean fileMoved = f.renameTo(new File(dir2, f.getName()));
                    //assert f.name == '1.txt' //**because File object is immutable, so I am just checking for the existing of previous file name. It is still there.
                    println fileMoved;
                }
            </groovy>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>
```

This code correctly prints the value of pattern, which is coming from attribute value. But the eachFileMatch function doesn't picks up the spec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            dir1.eachFileMatch  ~/pattern/, {
```

should be

```
            dir1.eachFileMatch  ~/${pattern}/, {
```

As pattern is a String variable, so you need to add it in to the regex pattern as such.

Previously, you were just searching for all files called `pattern`